# How we can perform data quality checks using Informatica Big data edition?

Tags: hive, informatica, bigdata

I need to know various ways in which we can perform data quality checks in informatica Big data edition.
We need to perform data quality checks in 100's of columns; most basics checks are data format check or number check etc.

Comment: Can you define your problem more precisely? For the majority of checks you will probably use Expression transformations and write statements that check the value and evaluate to true/false.

Comment: Informatica Data Quality is a dedicated tool for this kind of operations. However it's feasible to implement the whole solution in PowerCenter as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your question was specific to perform data quality on data in Hadoop or in pushdown mode, then you just enable the pushdown mode to enable the mapping to run I. hive/Hadoop run time environment, other wise everything is similar to a normal where in you code in Informatica developer tool.